# Why does scaleX cause absolutely positioned element to move leftward?

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms, pdf.js

I have an absolutely positioned parent containing bits of absolutely positioned text, which need to be stretched to match the underlying image. It looks something like this:

```
<div class="text-layer">
    <pre class="text-item">    some text   </pre>
    <pre class="text-item">    some text   </pre>
    <pre class="text-item">    some text   </pre>
</div>
```

When I'm placing the text items on the page, I have the (correct) left value for the snippet of text. However, some texts need to be stretched using the CSS transform property.

```
transform: scaleX(#)
```

When the div is stretched, it doesn't keep the same left position visually, in a way similar to this example:

```
1->     xxxxx
2->  xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like for the effect to be as follows.

```
1->     xxxxx
2->     xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Besides a fix, I am curious why 'left' does not take this into account. If I position an element at 'left:0', shouldn't it continue to have its 'left' edge there regardless of how it grows?

Edit for additional details:

```
      .my-canvas {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
      }

      .text-layer {
        color: transparent;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
```

An example text item looks like this:

```
<div class="text-item" 
     style="position: absolute; left: 80.5557355px; 
            top: 4.49999999999996px; font-size: 50px; 
            font-family: sans-serif; 
            transform: scaleX(2.58938106853314);">
     <span class="highlight">H</span>ELLO
</div>
```

Comment: we need your CSS too . (relative/absolute - transform-origin ? , ...)

Comment: Added more information about the structure / css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform-origin:` to set a origin point for your transforms.

I have made a codepen. here is the link
http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/QjWdQV

Comment: An excellent resource. Using transform-origin: left, I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted

Comment: Thanks.  transform-origin: is an important property. Good luck for ur project.